# Devise not saving password changes Rails 4, need to always trigger password reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

Stack:
Devise 3.1.1
Rails 4.0.5
Omniauth 1.2.2

I started running into this issue where users can reset their passwords (via email), but the changed password never gets saved. Basically the only way they can login is through password reset.

I'm not necessarily looking for a solution, but can anyone recommend how to DEBUG what is going on? Ideally I'd like to follow the password reset path within Devise so I can verify the new password is getting saved, but I don't know where to start looking or where to put "puts" statements.

Also, it only happens on SOME accounts, which is even weirder.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out a bug on my part. I was improperly overriding `find_first_by_auth_conditions`